# In a smart contract : If a specific exception is raised...can a Human decide and validate the Smart Contract?

Tags: contract-design

In a Ethereum Smart Contract : If a specific exception is raised...can a Human decide and validate the Smart Contract "by hand" ?

Comment: I'd question why anyone would trust a human more than they would the EVM... :-)

Comment: It's only in a specific exception...90% of the time the contract will be automatic .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code in an smart contract that when a particular situation happens, intervention from an external account is needed to complete a process. However, one of the main features Blockchain in general is trustlessness and the system that you describe will require the users of it to trust the external party that resolves the particular situation.